# query data by ID in ASP.Net MVC Core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to query the Product object from the database by using the ID. However, there was no data being sent to the View. I suspect that there is a problem with my Services and ProductController. I have try to use different methods to query the data
in the ProductServices file but none of them seems to work. Currently I don't know where the problem is.
[image: The error]

Below is my code for the ProductService

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace e_commerce.Data.Services
{
    public class ProductService : IProductService

    {
        private readonly ShopDbContext _context;
        public ProductService(ShopDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            _context.Products.Add(product);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            return _context.Products.ToList();
        }

        public void RemoveProduct(Product product)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Product UpdateProduct(Product product)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for ProductController

```
using e_commerce.Data.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace e_commerce.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProductService _service;

        public ProductController(IProductService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(_service.GetProducts());
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([Bind("ProductImageUrl, ProductName, ProductPrice")]Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(product);
            }
            _service.AddProduct(product);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var products = _service.GetProductById(id);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [The default value for reference and nullable types is `null`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) Therefore it's necessary to check for `null` after call to the `GetProductById()`. And you should pass the model to the view as the parameter: `return View(product)`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are not passing data with  a view

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
            var product = _service.GetProductById(id);
            if (product==null) product= new Product();
            return View(product);
}
```